# getting value of attribute to string vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to get the value of the `src` attribute (https://www.google.com) to a string from a web browser HTML elements. The code of element is:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com" height="500" width="500">
```

Code I have tried is:

```
    For Each o As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
        If o.GetAttribute("height") = "500" Then
            Dim url As String = o.GetAttribute("src").ToString

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

String `url` is empty every time I also tried to get `url` in textbox but its also empty.

Comment: What happens when you debug it?  Step through the code and examine the values?

Comment: Have you verified that there aren't any other images with `height="500"`?

Comment: @VisualVincent there is only one img tag

Comment: Make sure this code appears in the DocumentCompleted event handler.  Lots of web pages today use Javascript to generate content, it trundles along after DocumentCompleted with no decent "it is done" event to help you.  In which case you may need a timer to periodically check the page.

Comment: @HansPassant page is fully loaded. code is already in documentcompleted event

Comment: Then just write some debug code so you can see what is there, enumerate everything in Document.Body

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem is that  is not a server side control, it is plain html. to make matters worse there are not classes or ID's to make it easier to isolate which control u want to target. Also javascript could be generating that image so that could make it harder.

Comment: _"problem is that is not a server side control, it is plain html"_ - The OP isn't using ASP.NET either and I suspect it's not his website. He's using a web browser in WinForms which he lets take care of the parsing of the HTML, then he iterates the elements on the page. Like you said in the last part of your answer it is likely that the element is generated through Javascript.